# Equation involving Wilson's theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all primes $p$ such that
$$(p-1)!=p^k-1.$$
Where $k$ is a natural number.

Comment: If we consider that a number is a power of itself, then $2, 3, 5$ are examples.

Comment: A consequence is $(p-1)! \equiv -1 \bmod p^k$, and for $k = 2$ the only known solutions of this congruence are $p = 5, 13,$ and 563. Google the term "Wilson prime."  Of these, only 5 fits your original equation and the congruence for $k > 2$ has no known prime solutions. Your equation may be accessible to a special analysis, but it looks like the primes Dhruv mentioned are likely to be the only solutions. How did this question come up?

Answer (score 3):

this is a pretty known one:

for $p=2$, we have $2^k-1=1$ which gives $k=1$.

for $p=3$, we have $3^k-1=2$ which also gives $k=1$.

for $p=5$, we have $5^k-1=4!=24$ which gives $k=2$.

For $p>5$:

note that $p-1|(p-2)!$ for every prime $p>5$. Why?
Because $p-1=2\frac{p-1}{2}$ and given that $2$, and $\frac{p-1}{2}$ are smaller than $p-2$, not equal to each other and that the second one is integer (i.e. $p$ is odd), we can find both of them in $(p-2)!$ expansion.

If $2 \geq p-2$ then $p \leq 4$ so $p=2$ or $3$, contradiction. Similarly, if $\frac{p-1}{2}=p-2$ then $p=3$ and when $\frac{p-1}{2}=p-2$ then $p=5$, both contradicting $p>5$. Also,$p$ is even since $p>5>2$.

Therefore, $(p-1)^2|(p-1)!$ so $(p-1)^2|p^k-1=(p-1)(1+p+ \ldots +p^{k-1})$.

Therefore, $p-1|1+p+ \ldots +p^{k-1} \equiv 1+1+ \ldots +1 \equiv k \pmod{p-1}$.

Therefore, $p-1|k$.

This gives $p^{p-1}-1| \leq p^k-1=(p-1)!$ which after some routine gives $p=2$.

Indeed, after substitution, $(2,1),(3,1),(5,2)$ are the only solution pairs.

Comment: You haven't mentioned these two solutions: $(p,k)=(3, 1), (5,2)$ is also true.

Comment: Thank you!
I corrected it.